# Expected number of events using a multiset

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider events A, B, C, and D with probabilities of $1/6$, $1/2$, $1/12$, and $1/4$ respectively. A, B, C, and D are independent and mutually exclusive.

I am looking at sequences involving A occurring $6$ times, D can occur an infinite number of times, C occurring $0$ times, and B occurs once, and is always the end of the sequence.

To find the probability of this occurring I used:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac16\right)^6\frac12\left(\frac14\right)^n{6+n\choose6}$$which is about 8.03E-5.
I believe this part is correct.

In an effort to find the expected number of events that must occur before achieving the desired sequence type, I tried 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac16\right)^6\frac12\left(\frac14\right)^n{6+n\choose6}(n+7)$$

i.e. weighting the each probability by the number of events required to achieve the sequence. The result for this was 7.49E-4.

I am not sure how to interpret that number, or if I made a mistake somewhere. I would expect an event with such a small probability to require more events to take place. **Is** this a conditional probability (the number of expected events given the sequence occurs)? In that case I would divide by the probability, giving me a reasonable answer. I can see that being it, but I am not grasping that concept.

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have computed in the second summation is (almost) the [conditional expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) of the sequence length conditioned on the desired sequence type is achieved at all. And yes, to get the actual value for the conditional expectation you should also divide that by the probability of eventually achieving such a sequence.

In more detail,
$$\operatorname{E} (X | Y=y ) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} x \, \Pr(X=x|Y=y)= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x \ \frac{\Pr(X=x,Y=y)}{\Pr(Y=y)},$$
where in this case the event $X=x$ (the property is achieved at length $x$) is a subset of the event $Y=y$ (the property is achieved at whatever length), and therefore, 
$$\operatorname{E} (X | Y=y ) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x \ \frac{\Pr(X=x)}{\Pr(Y=y)},$$
What you have calculated is $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x \ {\Pr(X=x)}$, and if you divide it by $\Pr(Y=y)$ you get the conditional expectation.